# django included URLs with positional arguments

Tags: django, django-urls

In URL patterns, I'd like to capture a positional argument in a common prefix and pass it to included URLs, like so:

```
apis = [
  url(r'^data/(\d+)$', view, name='some.view'),
  ...
]

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^(\d+)/api/', include(apis)),
  ...
]
```

The Django documentation seems to imply that this will work, but the view only receives one argument instead of the expected two in the above example. What's wrong here?

This is in version 1.8.13.

Comment: How are you sure there isn't something else going wrong? And how are you accessing the parameters in the view?

Comment: To test it, I wrote a dummy view to print the arguments: `def view(request, *args, **kwargs): print args; print kwargs`. It prints only one argument.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't check it right this moment. I will try later. The only thing that I see as a potential issue is the lack of a trailing forward slash in the apis url. You might change it to `r'^data/(\d+)/$'` though I'm not sure that's actually going to fix anything. In my experience, Django is definitely picky with those trailing slashes, though.

Comment: The trailing slash did not make a difference. If it helps, it's receiving the captured argument from `'^data/(\d+)$'`, but not the one from `'^(\d+)/api/'`.

Comment: Hmm, that is problematic. I can see in the documentation that what you suggest *should* be valid: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters however, it seems that your attempt does not work. Like I said, I can try this later to see if I get different results.

Comment: I should note that keyword arguments _do_ work, and the example given in the documentation uses them. However, the documentation doesn't say anything specific about positional arguments in this case.

Comment: Is there any issue using the keyword arguments? I'd certainly be interested in solving this, but if it meant stopping everything until I did figure it out, I think I'd rather use the kwargs instead.

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: version 1.8.13 (stupid character limit)